# Java Transformation in Informatica

Tags: java, informatica-powercenter

Can I write sql queries in Java transformation?
Is there any possibilities?

I need to do query like this

```
String ID = select id from tablename where name='XXXX'.
```

Comment: I have never tried it, but I'm sure it's possible if you reference appropriate libraries to establish a database connection. However, why do you need to do it? Shouldn't you simply use a lookup?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use JDBC libraries with in Java transformation. You can download sample mapping demonstrating this functionality from Informatica Marketplace App

https://community.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_jdbc_read_java_transformation

Comment: @marek grzenkowicz thank you.what lookup transformation is? I m using Java TRansformation bcz i need generaterow(); functionality.Is this possible in lookup transformation?.please give ur guidelines

Comment: @user1601052 Lookup is transformation that retrieves a row that matches a condition - your query suggests that it's what you need to do. Try to explain your requirements in plain English - without talking about transformations and Java, **what do you need to do?**